# How do I Change Unit Size?

Tags: rome-total-war

What do I need to do in order to change the unit size (increase the number of soldiers per unit)?

I am stuck on normal size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an option in: Options -> Video -> Advanced. Advanced then leads to "Unit Size"